# Better Approach For The Results NSMutableArray in iOS search

Tags: objective-c, ios

So here's how I do the search:

1. I have an array of Data and a mutable array of search results
2. I perform the search
3. I fill an array with the results of a search using a predicate with the filterdArrayUsingPredicate:
4. add that array to the mutable array of results via `addObjectsFromArray:` as such:

   ```
   - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText 
                                scope:(NSString*)scope
   {
       NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                       predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                       searchText];

       NSArray *results = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

       NSMutableArray *myResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       [myResults addObjectsFromArray:results];

       self.searchResults = myResults;

       [myResults release];

       NSLog(@"%@", self.searchResults);
   }
   ```

The problem I see is that I have to create a mutable array everytime a search is performed, which is whenever a "keyup" occurs. I was wondering if there was a better approach with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wait, what? Why do you create that mutable array at all? Why not just self.searchResults = [self.allItems filtered...]?

Comment: that's how I see it in tutorials often. don't know why actually. They have a mutable array for results and add to that array, and I can't use filtered...] with Mutable Arrays

Comment: Yeah, only do that if you will at some point in the future need to add stuff to or otherwise modify that array. If not, don't do that. Also, yes you can call filtered... on mutable arrays, because mutable arrays inherit from NSArray, and thus a NSMutableArray can do everything an NSArray can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #4 is not makes sense. Assign filtered array directly but not thru myResults. In case of some internal logic you will need a copy of filtered results array you still can get it my calling copy method.